# Symfony display form errors of form created on rendered controller

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I'm rendering controller EmailControoler

```
 /**
 * @Route("/email", name="email")
 */
function insertEmailAction(Request $request)
{
    $request = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();

    $email = new Email();

    $form = $this->createForm(SendEmailType::class, $email);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($email);
        $em->flush();

        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        return $this->redirect($referer);

    }
     return $this->render('PTBEmailBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->CreateView(),
    ));

}
```

Inside twig template

```
{{ render(controller('PTBEmailBundle:Email:insertEmail', {'request':app.request})) }}
```

End everythink is all right, the form shows and inserts data into database. 
BUT if the form is not valid, user is redirected to route /email, what should I do to display form errors on rendered view? Thank you :D

Here's my Email entity:

```
    <?php

namespace DEERCMS\EmailBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * Email
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="email")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DEERCMS\EmailBundle\Repository\EmailRepository")
 */
class Email
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\Email(message="This is not valid e-mail")
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="addDate", type="datetime")
     */
    private $addDate;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->addDate = new \DateTime;
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return Email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set addDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $addDate
     *
     * @return Email
     */
    public function setAddDate($addDate)
    {
        $this->addDate = $addDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get addDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getAddDate()
    {
        return $this->addDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service) is stated, all you need to do is to check, in your action method, for validation rules you've set in the Entity class.

Something like:

```
$email = new Email();
// ...
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($email);
```

Then, if there are validation errors, just send them to the desired twig template:

```
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    return $this->render('default/whatever.html.twig', array(
        'errors' => $errors,
    ));
}
```

And finally, to display the errors:

```
{# app/Resources/views/default/whatever.html.twig #}
<h3>The email has the following errors</h3>
<ul>
    {% for error in errors %}
        <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Many thanks! As i thought this is the only one solution :D